# Taking all local-name of WebElement

Tags: selenium, xpath

Can I take all `local-name()` of WebElement?

I don't know the attributes of this webElement and I wish to find and save it.

**Edit**:

I have `WebElement` `elm` which it `tagName` is `Div`. I find this element by the next command:

```
WebElememnt elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*[identifier="c")).get(1)
```

Now, I want to know all the attributes of this element, which I don't know when I do my query. for example: elm is the next in my DOM:

```
<div identifier="c" someAtr="b" someAtr2="c">
```

So I wish to know that I have an attributes which it name is `"someAtr"="b"` and `"someAtr2"="c"` (Again, I don't know that `someAtr` even exists, and for that I want all the attributes).

Comment: Not knowing the attributes of a WebElement would make it quite difficult to identify. Are you saying you wish to retrieve all WebElements with the same name (`local-name`) and then save each of them? More info required.

Comment: There is no, out of the box, function that will return all the Attributes for a specific element. You may be able to achieve it by extending the **relevant** `WebElement` for your `WebDriver` for example `FirefoxWebElement`. Look at the `RemoteWebElement` class in the Selenium and see if you can build an executor for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the `Javascript Executor` and then getting the `innerHtml`:

```
String html = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", ele);
```

Then you can parse the `String` as you normally would.

Comment: This doesn't work when the WebElemnt has a child. Another thing is that with WebDriver I don't parse the Html at all. I can do it, by I prefer WebDriver funcion ot xpath syntax.

Comment: Well if you know the attributes that you're searching for, use `.getAttribute("attr")` but since you're explaining that you don't even know if the `element` has that attribute or not, using the `JS innerHTML` seemed a solution. Of course you could just create a series of `getAttributes()` surrounded by a try/catch so it doesn't blow up when the attributes aren't there.